# Question about electrical power in circuits

Tags: power-supply, power, circuit-analysis, current, current-source

I am a new student in electrical engineering. The text book told us that a current may be absorbed by a current source if the current passing through this source is passing from positive terminal. How can a current source absorb energy? I know that its purpose is to generate current, not absorb it. Is that true?

Comment: You're reading too much into it.  At this point, just look at the current source as a theoretical thing while you master the math..   Its not real.   In real life, if a current source were indeed forced to absorb current, the result likely would be spectacular flame and smoke.

Comment: "Absorb current" or "absorb power"?

Comment: @KyleB current sources often model devices or circuits that sink current and absorb power. For example a current mirror circuit.

Comment: @ThePhoton   Every physical model has limits.  For every rule there's a "but what about".  Of course there are exceptions.  There are ALWAYS exceptions.  Let the student learn the first order effects before you confuse him with other stuff.

Comment: @KyleB at the same time, don't teach them things that are only true for a very limited subset of the things that the model in question applies to,  like"the result likely would be spectacular flame and smoke"

Comment: Your question mentions absorbing current and absorbing energy. I trust you understand these are separate concepts. An ideal current source will supply or absorb whatever energy (or power) is required to maintain its set current. Similarly an ideal voltage source will supply or absorb whatever energy (or power) is required to maintain its set voltage. As discussed in other responses real world current or voltage sources can't do this and will only work within their stated specifications.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By example I can demonstrate how a current source can both absorb and emit energy. Take this simple circuit consisting of a single voltage source (a battery) and a resistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcqePU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On the left, the circuit is completely solved with a simple application of Ohm's law. Current I around the loop is:

$$ I = \frac{V}{R} = \frac{10V}{10\Omega} = 1A $$

On the right I added a simple current source of 1A, and I am monitoring the voltage across it with a voltmeter.

Understand that a current source is a device that produces whatever potential difference is required to obtain the current it is supposed to pass.

The potential difference provided by the battery, and presented across R1, is already sufficient to produce 1A through R1. If the current source were to add or subtract any voltage of its own to the loop, then that would cause something other than 1A to flow. In this case we are asking the current source to pass exactly 1A, but since that was already the case, it does not need to provide any extra potential difference. It must have 0V across it.

Now consider the case where we actually want less than 1A to flow through R1, say 0.9A. For that to be the case, we would require the voltage across R1 to drop to only 9V. If we instruct the current source to pass 0.9A, it complies by adopting its own potential difference of 1V.

Kirchoff's voltage law (KVL) is still obeyed, because the 1V across the current source, and the 9V voltage across R1 add up to the 10V of the battery, but now only 0.9A is flowing:

$$ I = \frac{9V}{10\Omega} = 0.9A $$

This is shown here, on the left:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiEe26.png)</sup>

On the right I have set the current source to pass 1.1A. For this to happen, the voltage across R2 must rise to 11V, which requires the current source to comply with a voltage of -1V across itself. Again KVL must be obeyed.

Now consider the power being dissipated or emitted by the current source. On the left:

$$ P = I \times V = 0.9A \times (+1V) = +0.9W $$

On the right:

$$ P = I \times V = 1.1A \times (-1V) = -1.1W $$

See how the power sign has changed? A positive power indicates that an element is absorbing energy. This is always the case, for example with a resistor, wherein current always flows from the side with higher potential to the side with lower potential.

If power is negative though, that's telling you that the element is a source of energy, delivering energy to the rest of the circuit. This is usually the case with batteries. When a battery is powering the circuit, current through it enters its lower potential termninal and exits via its higher potential terminal, the exact opposite of the behaviour of a resistor. By the power law, power dissipated in the battery in these circumstances is negative.

You recharge a battery by reversing the direction of current flow through it. To recharge it you must make current enter its positive terminal and leave from its negative terminal. In this way, the power calculation yields a positive value, indicating that the battery is receiving energy, not providing it.

By this logic, you can see that the current source in the circuit on the left is absorbing energy (which must of course come from the battery), and the source on the right is donating energy to the circuit (which is all being dissipated in the resistor).

Note that this is all in the context of two-terminal current sources, as you find in simulators. In practice, what we call a current source/sink is rarely a two terminal device that can act as both energy source and sink, since that requires it to be able to "adopt" voltages both positive and negative, and even permit currents in either direction. They would be classified as "four-quadrant" devices. It is possible to do, with opamps for example, but usually a "current source" like those found in the internals of ICs are "single-quadrant" designs, operating only with positive voltages across them, and currents through them in one direction only.

I was confused by your phrase "current may be absorbed by a current source". Every two-terminal device, current sources included, must obey Kirchhoff's Current Law, which in this case rules that current entering one end must equal current emerging at the other end. The word "absorb" tends to imply that current can enter without leaving, which is just not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Current sources can be hard to think about. We are surrounded by things that approximate well to voltage sources (power supplies, batteries) but few if any current sources, so we are not used to them.

In a simulator, an ideal current source produces a constant current through itself, while the terminal voltage is completely undefined. Contrast that to a simulator ideal voltage source, which produces a constant voltage, while the current through it is completely undefined.

In the ideal current source, if the voltage at the positive current output terminal is positive with respect to the other terminal, for instance if it is loaded by a resistor, then it will be generating power. If the voltage is zero, when loaded by a short circuit, then the output power is zero. If the voltage is negative, say there's a voltage source connected to it, then it will be absorbing power. It's a simple case of power = VI.

If we look at real current sources however, there will be practical limitations depending on how they are implemented, from available power, voltage headroom, ability to dissipate heat, and how closely they've been designed to approximate an ideal current source. Some current sources have been designed to both source and absorb power, depending on their terminal voltage. Most will not have been however, and would be damaged by reversing the output voltage.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, current sources can sink current. But be aware, not all current sources can sink current!

For example, commercial laboratory power supplies can operate as constant voltage or constant current source within their operating limits. But they usually support only positive current (current sourcing) as the technology to do that is much simpler.

There are supplies which can generate negative current (current sinking) but those are usually much more expensive. They usually “burn energy” on a resistor, or in case of higher power ratings (say few hundred Watts or more) they return the energy to the grid.

But current direction alone does not mean they source or sink energy. You also have to consider voltage direction, there are four quadrants in general:

1. Q1 positive voltage and positive current
2. Q2 negative voltage and positive current
3. Q3 negative voltage and negative current
4. Q4 positive voltage and negative current

Obviously, voltage times current is instantaneous power, and power sign determines direction of the energy flow.

I would suggest not to worry about these things in your introductory courses, there will be time later.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of circuit analysis, an ideal current source can either consume power or provide power to the circuit. The behavior of a current source is to **constrain** the current through it to some specified value. For example, when a MOSFET is operating in saturation, where the drain current is relatively constant, we might use a current source as a model for the behavior of the MOSFET.

Likewise, the behavior of an ideal voltage source is to **constrain** the voltage across it. We might use an ideal voltage source to represent a battery while it is being charged.